# How to turn a Python command line script script into mac .app?

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I've been googling like a madman trying to figure out how to turn a Python shell script into an .app file for MacOS. (I very very rarely use MacOS)

Example code (Actual code is pretty much the same but much bigger and spread out on multiple python files and contains some Selenium web automation)

```
import time
name = input("Name?: ")
print("Hello " + name)
time.sleep(10000)
```

Point being, I don't have tkinter or any other framework for a GUI.
Pretty much just want the .app to open as a terminal window for easy distribution to my Mac friends.

"pyinstaller --onefile --windowed script.py" does create an .app file, but it just instantly closes without any error code.

[Platypus](https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) didn't work at all, in any way shape or form.

EDIT: Using pyinstaller to compile the python script to an exe works just fine for Windows.

Comment: have you tried running the app from a terminal?

Comment: @Alexander Yes I have using "open appname.app", again the App icons appears in the dock as open for a split second then disappears and the terminal doesn't output any error message.

Comment: have you tried not using the --windowed command line flag?

Comment: @Alexander Yes that works fine, but then I only get the script file, not an .app

Comment: So it doesn't give any errors when  you run the script file?

Comment: @Alexander Correct, when running the script file it launches just as it should in a terminal window.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want a .app -- an app runs as an independent member of the GUI interface, not inside another app (which is what Terminal is). (There are exceptions, but they're not relevant here.) It sounds more like you want to add .command to the script's filename, which makes it a Terminal document, so it'll open in Terminal.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes and no. It works just fine the way it is now. My goal with turning the script into an .app is to be able to add it to the dashboard and dock.
From a lot more Googling it seems I'd have to add a GUI with tkinter or other interface to get a proper .app